# Using a regex to match www.test.com, test.com and www.test.org, but not test.org

Tags: regex, perl, nginx

[Nginx can use Perl regular expressions for listening on different virtual hosts/server names, among many things.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) I'm trying to create a regex to match the a domain with different TLDs, with the exception of one without the www subdomain. I've been using RegExr to help me create an initial regex and have done some reading to try and further my understanding but I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this.

I've been trying to create a Regex to match the following:

```
test.com (match)
www.test.com (match)
test.org (fail)
www.test.org (match)
test.net (match)
www.test.net (match)
test.biz (match)
www.test.biz (match)
```

So far I've got:

```
~^(www\.|)test\.(com|org|net|biz)$
```

as an initial regex, but I'm not sure how to add an exception to achieve what I want.

Many thanks and sorry if this seems simple. (First time creating regular expressions as you can probably tell.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(www\.test\.org|(www\.)?test\.(com|net|biz))$` is the straightforward way — just make the exception fully an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you on the PCRE regex part, but there's a chance the nginx part has a hiccup.

```
~^(?!test\.org)(?:www\.)?test\.(?:com|org|net|biz)$
```

This uses a negative look-ahead to ensure the string cannot match "test.org" and then goes on to have an optional prefixing "www." before your "test." and TLD.

You can find [a more thorough walk-through](https://regex101.com/r/rE8pM2/1) of this (or any regex), as well as noting the performance on each of the tests you offered, at regex101.com (never mind the flags I added, those merely ensure that the test domains are all matched in this environment).